# Kurdish is currently available in Google Translate, but has not yet been added to the flutter_localization

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations

Kurdish is currently available in **[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ckb&tl=en&op=translate)** , but has not yet been added to the flutter_localization package! How can I add Kurdish language ? Because we really need to have Kurdish language officially in our apps. Kurdistan country code is "**ckb**".

Thanks.

Comment: check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_kurdish_localization), or contribute to other localization packages like [this](https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @hewajalal Flutter_localization package includes all other languages ​​but not Kurdish. I wanted to add it officially some time ago but they told me your language is not official.  I don't want to use any other packages. I want to add them officially.

Comment: Disclaimer: `ckb` is not a country code, it is Central Kurdish's code.